# Clone git repo through ssh tunnel from windows

Tags: git, ssh

I have a git repo on a machine which is behind a firewall. I am able to tunnel to that machine via another machine. These two machines are different flavours of Linux, and I can't really modify the middle machine.

I can happily git away from my Linux laptop using my ssh config file, along the lines of:

```
Host git-machine
    ProxyCommand ssh middle-machine nc %h 22
```

However, I have a Windows 7 laptop that I must use while travelling for work (and I am not going to carry two laptops), and I'm trying to work out how to connect to git repo from Windows.

Can [or how can] I connect to the firewalled git repo from Windows?

Comment: Git for Windows ships a Windows build of the stock OpenSSH client which, among other things, supports the standard OpenSSH configuration such you've just showed.

Comment: I just realised this myself. I am feeling quite the fool! I created a config file and it is now working as expected. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is to create a config file for the `OpenSSH` as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring) or [here](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-ssh-configfiles.html)